# Is it possible to do simple arithmetic (e.g. addition) on "compressed" integers?

Tags: c++

I would like to compress an an array of integers, initially initialized to 0, using a yet-to-be-determined integer compression/decompression method.

Is it possible with some integer compression method to increment (+1) a specific element of an array of compressed integers accurately using C or C++?

Comment: What is a "compressed integer"?

Comment: That would be pretty hard to determine without knowing the compression method...

Comment: tenfour, a compressed integer is an integer that has been compressed into some smaller bitfield representation using some compression method (run length encoding , Lempel - Ziv Welch, etc.

Comment: mydogisbox, Suppose we use Lempel - Ziv - Welch or run length enconing, Would it possible to increment the LZW or RLE encoding? Thank you.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know little about compression algorithms, however I would hazard that the compressed format does not account for the data that is compressed, so how could you possibly know which bits in which bytes represent the integer at the index you want - even if you knew the algorithm and the index, I doubt it's possible as you need to know how the previous integers were compressed to give you a correct index - which means you need to know the values...

Comment: My answer to this question is yet to be determined.

Comment: There is no way you are going to find a more efficient method than decompress -> modify -> recompress. But that doesn't mean you can't optimize the scenario in general. For example, maybe you can store a list of changes to the set that can be applied when the set needs to be read.

Comment: Nim, Your assessment is very valuable. We were hoping to avoid decompressing the LZW,RLE encoding prior to incrementing. we were hoping that there was some compression algorithm that would allow to us increment encoded values without decompressing first. Thank you.

Comment: tenfour, Your idea of storing a list of the deltas sounds promising. What would be the memory requirements and best data structure required to store the list of deltas? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: If you don't know the algorithm, how could anyone possibly answer the question?

Comment: DeadMG, Your point is valid. However, there are so many data compression methods, we were not able to read the details of all these data compression methods. Does there exists data compression method which has the mathematical property that encoded integers can be incremented accurately?

Comment: DeadMG, I just found a data compression technique 'Elias Integer Encoding' which allows accurate arithmetic operations on encoded integers. Here is the URL http://lc.fie.umich.mx/~sadit/papers/jcc2010intenc.pdf . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly implement this, if your increment method:

1. Decompresses the entire array.
2. Increments the desired entry.
3. Compresses the entire array again.

If you want to increment in less of a dumb way you'll need intimate knowledge of the compression process, and so would we to give you more assistance.

Comment: RobH, I understand your answer. Before we can tell you the compression process, we know if it is practically feasible to increment the result of a integer encoding or whether there are any workarounds like tenfour's. Thank you.

Comment: @frank Again, it depends entirely on the encoding. Say I chose the encoding "pack the lower 16 bits of two numbers into the high and low words of a single 32 bit entry", then it would be possible. If OTOH a run-length encoding was used then it would not be practical to increment in-place.

Comment: For instance, say you run-length encode an array of a million zeroes, with the result written to two 32 bit integers - a zero, followed by one million. To increment a value in the middle of the sequence would require one to re-write the whole compressed block.

Comment: I think I understand the point you are making about run length array encoding. exOdu5 just suggested using a sparse array. Are there are any methods which you suggest? THank you.

Comment: RobH, I just found a data compression technique 'Elias Integer Encoding' which allows accurate arithmetic operations on encoded integers. Here is the url 'Operators over Compressed Integer Encodings ' http://lc.fie.umich.mx/~sadit/papers/jcc2010intenc.pdf . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Of all the common compression techniques, two stand out as potentially usable in this without a full decompress cycle.

First, sparse arrays were built specifically for this.  With a sparse array, you typically store a map of index to value.  You don't store array elements that haven't been modified, so if most of your array is 0, it need not be stored.  Many arrays (and matrices) in simulations are sparse, and there's a huge literature.  Here adding to a value would simply be accessing the index with [] and incrementing - the access will create if nonexistent.

Next, run length encoding may also work if you find that you are working with large sequences of the same number, but those "runs" are not all the same number.  Since they are not the same, a sparse array would not work and RLE is a solution.  Incrementing a number is not as easy as for sparse, but basically if not a run, you add and check to see if you can make a new run.  If part of a run, you split the run.  RLE typically only makes sense with visual data or certain mathematical patterns.

Comment: @exOdu5, Thank you for your excellent answer. we will investigate your sparse array further. Could we use a Standard Template Library map to implement your proposed idea of storing a map of index(array) to value? Also, what happens if the sparse array starts to become a more heavily populated array?

Comment: @Frank: you certainly can use a std::map.  They are often the best solution complexity-wise, though the hash forms can be useful in some usage patterns.

Comment: exOdu5, When you say that "Though the hash forms can be useful in some usage patterns", what type of hash forms are you referring to? Could it be a "randomized" hash table? Also,  what happens if the sparse array becomes less sparse over time? THank you.

Comment: @Frank: I just meant that sometimes the std::unordered_map class from the standard library can give good complexity guarantees, but usually std::map was better for the usages of sparse arrays I've seen.  The problem is iterating through the whole collection.  An unordered_map will not do iterate in order, so if you need this, the complexity skyrockets and it's best to stick with std::map.  If the sparse array gets less sparse over time, then there comes a point (before half full) where it takes more space than the basic array.  If it will get that large, use the array in the first place.

Comment: ex0du5, We will try your sparse array idea with std::map. If the sparse array becomes 50+% could we use Elias Integer Encoding. I just found a data compression technique 'Elias Integer Encoding' which allows accurate arithmetic operations on encoded integers. Here is the url 'Operators over Compressed Integer Encodings ' <http://lc.fie.umich.mx/~sadit/papers/jcc2010intenc.pdf> . Thank you.

Comment: exOdu5, THere is a http:// that is necesarry before http://lc.fie.umich.mx/~sadit/papers/jcc2010intenc.pdf. I apologize for the misspelling. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Note that this method you are looking at based on Elias coding does not provide better complexity benefits for it's operations as it is effectively a slower map for searches.  Also, like all Huffman-type codings, the dictionary which must also be stored adds space.  You only actually get compression if you have enough similar numbers that they outweigh the overhead.  If every number is different, you again do better with an array.  With that caveat, though, the technique you found looks like a good fit, as incremented numbers will fall towards small ints with good overlap.

Comment: exOdu5, Thank you for your excellent assessment of the Elias Integer Coding method. BTW, I accepted your answer hours ago.